# No rows to manipulate in html table created with jQuery csvToTable?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter, import-from-csv

I am a novice programmer and am hoping for some help with the following situation.

I am able to read in a local external CSV file and display as an HTML table with jQuery csvToTable http://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/.  I am also able to sort the table with the jQuery plugin tablesorter http://tablesorter.com/docs/.  Now, I would like to improve the look and interactivity of the table, but I cannot seem to manipulate rows in the HTML table, for example, to do what should be simple things like highlighting on mouseover or applying different colors to odd and even rows (e.g. I cannot get the 'zebra' widget in tablesorter to work).  I can, on the other hand, modify the color of the entire table, but this is not the real goal.  All of this makes me think that, despite the appearance of a well-formatted HTML table created by csvToTable, there may not actually be any table rows there to manipulate at all.

I know there could be something very basic that I am missing due to my lack of experience, so sorry in advance if that turns out to be the case.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Fyi, I am also using The Uniform Server.

CSV:

```
id,name,pop11
1,Allen,28456
2,Brown,106094
3,Center,53153
4,Denver,101345
5,Ellen,64769
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.csvToTable.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.tablesorter.min.js'></script>

<table id="CSVTable" border="1px solid black" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;"></table>


<script>

/* Reading CSV data from local external file, creating HTML table, and preparing for tablesorter */

$('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('testdata.csv', 
{ 
   loadingImage: 'loading.gif', 
   startLine: 1,
   headers: ['id', 'name', 'pop11']
}
).bind("loadComplete",function() { 
$(document).find('#CSVTable').tablesorter();
});

/* Applying tablesorter */

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#CSVTable").tablesorter();

});

/* Optional below - showing able to change color of the entire table */

/*

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("table").css("background-color","#1C86EE");
});
*/

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your <table> should be in the <body> of your document.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, watson.  I have moved the scripts and <table> into the body of the document, but I am still stuck where I was before.

Comment: Can you post the code that you get if you view source after your page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't initialize tablesorter twice. Keep the initialization code inside of the  "loadComplete" callback function, then add the `widgets` option to include the zebra widget:

```
/* Reading CSV data from local external file, creating HTML table, and preparing for tablesorter */

$('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('testdata.csv', {
    loadingImage: 'loading.gif', 
    startLine: 1,
    headers: ['id', 'name', 'pop11']
}).bind("loadComplete",function() { 
    $(document).find('#CSVTable').tablesorter({
        widgets : ['zebra'] // include the zebra widget
    });
});

/* Applying tablesorter */
// **** Remove the code below ****
// $(document).ready(function() 
// { 
//    $("#CSVTable").tablesorter();
// });
```

Alternatively, you could follow watson's advise and use css to style the even rows. The only real reason to use the zebra widget over css is if you have hidden rows within your table, or because of a lack of browser support (IE7-8).

Answer (score 2):

You need some css! try this out:

```
<style type="text/css">
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: aqua;
}
</style>
```

Add it to the  of your page.
For Hover:

```
table tr:hover {
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I changed the "ccc" to "css" and that did the trick!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there other stuff you want to know how to do, besides making the even rows some color?

Comment: how about an upvote, unless this was not the answer you wanted.

Comment: On the upvote: I tried, but it says that requires 15 reputation and I only have 1 now.

Comment: I would like to add highlighting on hover or mouseover.  Any recommendations?  I'm trying, but not yet succeeding, with jQuery tableHover <http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html>.

Comment: I see my reputation is slowly increasing - I promise to upvote once I hit 15.

Comment: A question on highlighting table rows:  I still cannot seem to reference table rows to highlight them, even using CSS as simple as this example <http://juicystudio.com/cognitive/example16.htm>, but I know table rows exist since your CSS worked.  Why is this happening?  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no matter what validated CSS I add, the only CSS that shows up is your code to alternate row colors and the code to set the background color for the table headers.  Perhaps I should start another thread based on this issue.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: +1 for your css solution, but wow your color choices... *eyes burning* LOL

Comment: Thank you, watson and Mottie, for your help!  I don't know what changed, but after restarting my computer, both of the solutions you suggested worked!  My reputation is currently at 11, but I will upvote both approaches once I hit the required minimum of 15.  I really appreciate both of you sharing your time and and wisdom with a rookie!  Thanks again!