# csvtotable populate 2 different tables in a html

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am a novice in JS and Jquery , 
i just tried the explanations from ([No rows to manipulate in html table created with jQuery csvToTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881122/no-rows-to-manipulate-in-html-table-created-with-jquery-csvtotable)) and i was able to Get the Table data from my CSV , while when i try to populate two different Tables ( referred when... then syntax of JS to control function executions one by one) i am not getting any table data rendered.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

I tried something like the below

`<script>
    $.when( $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('test.csv');).then($('#CSVTable1').CSVToTable('test1.csv'));
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="CSVTable" border="1px solid black" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;"></table>
    <div> hi </div>
    <table id="CSVTable1" border="1px solid black" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;"></table>`

Answer (score 0):

Just found out one useful , logic here http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready/

Just calling them over different target div with two document.ready functions , helped it !!